# Class function to return different objects

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server-ce

In short I am writing a class handler to handle to database integration of some software I am writing for myself, however as there is not always a connection to the remote database I thought I would use SQLCE to create a local database buffer so when a connection is made the changes can be synchronized.

So far it is going well except for the parameters.  The function I am looking to call is shown below however this function is complaining about invalid arguments.

```
public Object run(string query, List<Object> dbparams = null)
    {
        if (MyDB.isConnected())
        {
            return MyDB.run(query, dbparams);
        }
        else
        {
            SqlCeCommand sql = _OfflineConnection.CreateCommand();
            sql.CommandText = query;
            if (dbparams.Count > 0)
            {
                sql.Parameters.AddRange(dbparams.ToArray());
            }
            return sql;
        }
    }
```

MyDB.run is the exact same code as in the else statement except for mysql, the line that it is moaning about is the return mydb.run as the mydb class is expecting the dbparams list to be of mysqlparameters.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?  I attempted to use LINQ to do a convert but that failed miserably.

**EDIT**

At present I have the following working but I am sure there is a cleaner solution

```
public Object run(string query, List<Object> dbparams = null)
    {
        if (MyDB.isConnected())
        {
            List<MySqlParameter> mydbparams = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < dbparams.Count; i++)
            {
                mydbparams.Add((MySqlParameter)dbparams[i]);
            }
            return MyDB.run(query, mydbparams);
        }
        else
        {
            SqlCeCommand sql = _OfflineConnection.CreateCommand();
            sql.CommandText = query;
            if (dbparams.Count > 0)
            {
                sql.Parameters.AddRange(dbparams.ToArray());
            }
            return sql;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I guess in the else branch you should create and open the SqlCeConnection to the sdf file. Maybe this implemented somewhere inside _OfflineConnection, but this is not clear.

Comment: @kol the issue here is only this part of the code, all other handles are already covered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit cleaner solution would be

```
mydbparams = dbparams.Cast<MySqlParameters>().ToList();
```

Also, you should check for and handle the null condition of `dbparams`.

Comment: Thanks Eren, I now have another issue where as I can't use the using () statement to handle to code neatly :(